# Uploading the whole sqlite database to google app engine

Tags: android, sqlite, google-app-engine

I just want to know if it is possible to upload from an android phone the whole sqlite database to google app engine and then download it from there to my computer.

Comment: Is your final goal downloading the database to your computer?

Comment: yes.remotely... cos the app is not running just on one phone

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know any app-engine stuff. Though what you could do is upload the database file to a remote server.

Comment: app engine could be configured as a server... so assume it is a server, how do i upload sqlite database from android phone to anywhere. let's say that i am not even using a server but my email account instead. How can I sent the database to my email or even in general to a remote place?

Answer (score 1):

*This is based on the conversation that I and @JustCurious had in the question comments*

You can get the DB file as follows

> String path = getDatabasePath("myDB.db").getAbsolutePath() + "/myDB.db"

and Email it out

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+ path));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The DB is just a file, you need to get the path to it, and then post it to App Engine. Depending on the size of the DB, you might need to use the Blobstore, there is a limit to the size you can store in a regular entity.

Comment: I am not familiar with Google Storage. Is there an easy way to export it there?

Comment: Maybe you mean to comment on the other answer? Google Cloud Storage is  different from the app engine data store, although you can access it from app engine. You can use it to upload files, but you'd have to think about how to handle permissions. You probably wouldn't want anyone to be able upload to your account.

Comment: oopss. It was meant for the answer above. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You mean uploading to GAE Blobstore?
It might be a better idea to upload it to Google Storage rather than app engine if you really want to just dump the file